# With a rejection area $R=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2|x^2\geq cy^2\}$, what is value of $c$ with given hypothesis?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing

$\mu\in\mathbb{R},\sigma^2\gt0$

$X$ and $Y$ are random variables which are independent each other and follow $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $N(0,\sigma^2)$.

To test $$H_0:\mu=0 \\\ H_1:\mu\neq0$$

we consider the rejection area $$R=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2|x^2\geq cy^2\}$$

that is , when $(X,Y) \in R$, reject $H_0$.

$c$ is a constant value.

When we set a level of significance $\alpha(0\lt\alpha\lt1)$, what is a value of $c$?

---

I set $$P(X^2\geq cY^2|\mu=0)=\alpha$$
Then if I suppose $H_0$ is correct, $X$ and $Y$ has the same distribution,

then $$P(Y^2\geq cY^2) =\alpha \\\ P(1\geq c)=\alpha$$

I got stuck here, but could not see where I went wrong.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ has the same distribution under $H_0$ does not mean $X=Y$ under $H_0$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom How should I have moved on from $P(X^2\geq cY^2|\mu=0)=\alpha$?

Comment: One way is to write the inequality as $X^2/Y^2\ge c$ Now assuming $\sigma$ is known, $X^2/\sigma^2$ and $Y^2/\sigma^2$ are independent chi-square variables.

Comment: @StubbornAtom so can we say that $\frac{X2}{\sigma^2}$ and $\frac{Y^2}{\sigma^2}$ follow chi-square with $(n-1)$ df and $\frac{\frac{X2}{\sigma^2}}{\frac{Y^2}{\sigma^2}}$  follow the $F(1,1)$?

Comment: $X^2/\sigma^2$ and $Y^2/\sigma^2$ are independent $\chi^2_1$ (assuming $\sigma$ is given) under $H_0$, so $X^2/Y^2\sim F_{1,1}$ under $H_0$. You can also do this in terms of $X/Y$ since $X/Y=\frac{X/\sigma}{Y/\sigma}$ has a standard Cauchy or a $t_1$ distribution under $H_0$.